# Creating Unique URI Slugs - is this a Recursive Trigger? (SQL Server)

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, triggers, slug, recursive-query

Here's my table:

**dbo.Posts**

- PostId (IDENTITY, PK)
- Subject
- UniqueUri (NVARCHAR(350), NOT NULL)

When i create a "Post", i insert a blank *UniqueUri* (using the `NEWID()` built-in function).

I then have a trigger on the "Post" table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[OnAfterInsertUpdatePostTrigger]
   ON  [dbo].[Posts]
   AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @PostIds IdentityType

    INSERT INTO @PostIds
    SELECT PostId
    FROM INSERTED

    -- Create the UniqueUri's.
    EXECUTE [dbo].[UpdatePostsCleanedUriUniqueUri] @PostIds

END
```

Which calls a SPROC to create the Unique Uri's.

The SPROC has some code like this:

```
UPDATE a
    SET a.CleanedUri = NEWID(),
        a.UniqueUri = NEWID()
    FROM [dbo].[Posts] a
        INNER JOIN @PostIds b ON a.PostId = b.Id
```

I noticed when i tried to insert only a single post, it was taking over a minute.

I can only deduce this is a recursive trigger call?

Basically, when a Post is created/updated, i need to create unique uri's (much like stack, for questions).

The only solution i can think of is created another table called UniqueUri's, which would have nothing but the PostId FK and the Uri, e.g a 1-1, which i always try to avoid.

Then the SPROC would update that table.

Any other suggestions/ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution to prevent the trigger recursively firing is to eliminate changes to your columns from the trigger:

```
IF ( NOT UPDATE (CleanedUri) AND NOT UPDATE (UniqueUri ) )
BEGIN
    DECLARE @PostIds IdentityType      
    INSERT INTO @PostIds     
    SELECT PostId     
    FROM INSERTED      

    -- Create the UniqueUri's.     
    EXECUTE [dbo].[UpdatePostsCleanedUriUniqueUri] @PostIds 
END;
```

Comment: This does work - but the problem in the end was a missing index on a GEOGRAPHY table (and missing indexes here can kill you), so that was the problem, not a recursive trigger. However, i'll accept this answer because if it *was* a recursive call, this would solve the problem. Thanks!